Making NSum faster with higher precision and accuracy
I have the following code that I want to run to obtain a cumulative list out of various values of s1=3 to s1=10 (say) for the function spinpiece defined below at last
Cfree[l_] = (2 Gamma[l + h - 1]^2 Gamma[l + 2 h - 3])/(
  l! Gamma[h - 1]^2 Gamma[2 h + 2 l - 3]);
\[Delta]3[l_] = 
  1/(5832 l^2 (l + 1)^3) (324 + 12 (59 - 22 l) l - 
     432 l (l + 1)^2 HarmonicNumber[l]^2 + 
     2 (l + 1) HarmonicNumber[
       l] (-162 + l (24 + l (241 + 109 l (l + 2))) + 
        216 l (l + 1) HarmonicNumber[2 l]) + (l + 
        1) ((324 - l (-384 + l (373 + 109 l (l + 2)))) HarmonicNumber[
          2 l] + 54 l (l + 
           1) ((-8 + 3 l (l + 1)) HarmonicNumber[l, 2] - 
           2 (l - 2) (l + 3) HarmonicNumber[2 l, 2])));

sDim[l_, \[Epsilon]_] = 
  2 - \[Epsilon] + 
   l + (1 - 6/(l (l + 1))) \[Epsilon]^2/
    54 + (1/(
      5832 l^2 (l + 1)^2) (373 l^2 - 384 l - 324 + 109 l^3 (l + 2) - 
        432 l (l + 1) HarmonicNumber[l])) \[Epsilon]^3;

op[l_] = 
 Cfree[l] (1 + \[Epsilon]^2 1/(
        54 l (l + 1)) (6 (l + 1)^-1 + 
          2 (l^2 + l - 3) HarmonicNumber[
            l] - (l - 2) (l + 3) HarmonicNumber[2 l]) + \[Delta]3[
         l] \[Epsilon]^3) /. {h -> 2 - \[Epsilon]/2} // 
   Series[#, {\[Epsilon], 0, 3}] & // Normal


\[Mu][\[CapitalDelta]_, l_, n_, m_] = 
  1/(m! (l - m - n)! n!) (-1)^(m + n)
    2^-l l! HypergeometricPFQ[{-m, 1 - h - l/2 + \[CapitalDelta]/2, 
     1 - h - l/2 + \[CapitalDelta]/2, -1 + n + \[CapitalDelta]}, {l/
      2 - m + \[CapitalDelta]/2, -(l/2) + n + \[CapitalDelta]/2, 
     2 - 2 h - l + \[CapitalDelta]}, 
    1] Pochhammer[-1 + h + l, -m] Pochhammer[-1 + 
     l + \[CapitalDelta], -l + n] Pochhammer[
    n + 1/2 (-l + \[CapitalDelta]), l - n] Pochhammer[
    m + n + 1/2 (-l + \[CapitalDelta]), 
    l - m - n] Pochhammer[-m + (l + \[CapitalDelta])/2, m];

\[CapitalNu][\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = 
  FunctionExpand[((2^
       l (\[CapitalDelta] + l - 1) Gamma[\[CapitalDelta] + l - 
         1]^2 Gamma[\[CapitalDelta] - h + 
         1])/(Gamma[\[CapitalDelta] - 1] Gamma[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/
        2]^4 Gamma[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] - ((\[CapitalDelta] - l)/
          2)]^2 Gamma[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] - (
         2 h - \[CapitalDelta] - l)/2]^2)), 
   Assumptions -> {\[CapitalDelta] \[Element] Integers, 
     l \[Element] Integers, \[CapitalDelta] >= 0, l >= 0}];

s2p[s_, \[Eta]_] = -(1/2) s (1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 \[Eta]]);


P[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_, s_, t_, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]_, h_] = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(u = 0\), \(l\)]\((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(v = 0\), \(l - 
        u\)]\[Mu][\[CapitalDelta], l, v, u]\ Pochhammer[
\*FractionBox[\(\[CapitalDelta] - l\), \(2\)] - s, 
        u]\ Pochhammer[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] - t, v])\)\) /. {s -> 
     s + 2 \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]/3, 
    t -> t + 2 \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]/3};

R[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_, k_, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]_, h_] = (
  Gamma[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2 + \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] - 
     h]^2 Pochhammer[
    1 + (\[CapitalDelta] - l)/2 - \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], k]^2)/(
  Factorial[k] Gamma[\[CapitalDelta] - h + 1 + k]);

Q[\[CapitalDelta]_, \[ScriptL]_, k_, s1_, s2_, 
   s3_, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]_, h_] = 
  R[\[CapitalDelta], \[ScriptL], k, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], 
    h] P[\[CapitalDelta], \[ScriptL], \[Tau]k, 
    s2p[\[Tau]k, (-s1 s2 s3)/\[Tau]k^3], \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], h];

H[\[Sigma]_, s1_, s2_, s3_] = 
  1/((\[Sigma] - s1) (\[Sigma] - s2) (\[Sigma] - s3));

DispB[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_, k_, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]_, s1_, s2_] = 
  1/\[Tau]k ((2 \[Tau]k^3 + s1 s2 (-s1 - s2)) Q[\[CapitalDelta], l, k,
        s1, s2, -s1 - s2, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], h] H[\[Tau]k, s1, 
       s2, -s1 - s2] - 
     2 Q[\[CapitalDelta], l, k, 0, 0, 0, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], h]);

spinpiece[s1_, l_, 
  kmax_] := \[CapitalNu][sDim[l, \[Epsilon]], l] op[l] DispB[
         sDim[l, \[Epsilon]], l, k, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], s1, 
         0] /. {\[Tau]k -> (sDim[l, \[Epsilon]] - l)/2 + k - (
          2 \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi])/3} /. {\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] -> 
        1 - \[Epsilon]/2 + \[Epsilon]^2/108 + 
         109/108^2 \[Epsilon]^3} /. {h -> 
       2 - \[Epsilon]/2} /. {\[Epsilon] -> 1/10} // Simplify // 
  NSum[#, {k, 0, kmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 30, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 30] &

kmax truncates the NSum to the desired value and I have set it to kmax=1000 for now. I want a cumulative list for values of l = 4 to l = 50 for just the even numbers. I use the following code by a kind stranger as the answer to my previous question (here for ex s1=3)
dataset = 
 FoldList[#1 + spinpiece[3, #2, 1000] &, spinpiece[3, 4, 1000], 
  Range[6, 50, 2]]

This gives me the cumulative list that I want. But the problem is that I want high precision so that I am able to do a non-linear fit on the elements of the last element of each list from s1=3 to s1=10. But even setting the values of PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal to very high values, the final precision in the answer drops and this calculation takes me a lot of time and I need it fast. Is there any way to do this thing faster? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Could you take a moment and turn your definition of P so it doesn't have UnderoverscriptBox and FractionBox in it? That would make it easier for some to scrape-n-paste your code.  And, is there any chance it might be possible to use Sum instead of NSum? That might give you a large exact symbolic solution and then Simplify to eliminate stuff causing numeric problems and then as the very last step N[yourresult,precisionyouwant] I fiddled with your code a bit to see if I could do that but I may have made some mistakes and ruined it. That might possibly be faster.
